# Adding object to let constant NSMutableDictionary works, but why?

Tags: swift, constants, nsmutabledictionary, let, swift2

I've been trying to figure out why it's possible to add objects to a let constant dictionary, but cannot find the answer.

The code below works, but I've always thought of let constants as immutable objects.

Anyone that can shed som light on this?

```
        // Create dictionary to allow for later addition of data
    let data: NSMutableDictionary = ([
        "firstname" : "john",
        "lastname" : "doe"
    ])

    // Add email to dictionary if e-mail is not empty
    if email != "" {
        data.setValue(email, forKey: "email")
    }
```

Comment: Do not use `NSMutableDictionary` in Swift, it does more harm than good. And do not use `setValue:forKey` unless you have a distinct idea what KVC is and why you are using it. The *constant* of a reference type is the reference not the containing data.

Comment: And why do think adding an object to the `NSMutableDictionary` should fail? You aren't trying to modify the variable `data`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift the `let` keyword is used to declare a constant. However, there are some things you need to be aware of depending on if you are declaring a constant for a **reference** type or a **value** type.

### Reference Type

```
// Declare a class (which is a reference type)
class Foo {
    var x = 1
}

// foo's reference is a constant. 
// The properties are not unless they are themselves declared as constants.
let foo = Foo()

// This is fine, we are not changing the foo reference.
foo.x = 2

// This would result in a compiler error as we cannot change 
// the reference since foo was declared as a constant.
foo = Foo()
```

### Value Type

```
// Declare a struct (which is a value type)
struct Bar {
    var y = 1 // Note the var
}

// bar's value is a constant. The constant nature of the value type properties 
// that are part of this value are subject to bar's declaration.
let bar = Bar()

// This would result in a compiler error as we cannot change 
// the value of bar.
bar.y = 2
```

### Mixture of Reference and Value Types

Generally you wouldn't want to have a reference type property defined on a value type. This is for illustrative purposes.

```
// Declare a struct (which is a value type)
struct Car {
    let foo = Foo() // This a reference type
}

// The value is a constant. But in this case since the property foo 
// is declared as a constant reference type, then the reference itself 
// is immutable but its x property is mutable since its declared as a var.
let car = Car()

// This is fine. The x property on the foo reference type is mutable.
car.foo.x = 2
```

Since `NSMutableDictionary` is a class, declaring the reference as a constant ensures you cannot change its **reference**, however its mutable properties can be changed.

The comment on your question from @vadian regarding `NSMutableDictionary` should be noted.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough explanation! I have also noted the comment from @vadian. :)